# Calculate e values for user n values?

Tags: c

I have a question about C Programming

I want to write a program calculate e values for user enter the n values.

You know ; we can define x=pow(1+1/n,n) for n=1,2.. It can be shown  mathematically that x->e as n - > infinite.

How can i do this ?

i have done this yet ,i'm tried but i didn't work like i said :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n,x1;

    printf("Enter a n value:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

        for (i = 0;; i++)
        {
            x1 = pow((1 + 1 / n), n);
            printf("Values:%d",x1);
        }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop with no condition, and you never use the loop variable `i` inside the loop, instead you repeat everything for the same `n` over and over.

Comment: … and after the end of the endless loop, pause. Just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

```
1 / n
```

is an expression with two integer operands. And so performs integer division. For `n` equal to `1`, this evaluates to `1`. For all values of `n` greater than `1` this integer division evaluates to `0`.

You want floating point division and so must make at least one of the operands a floating point value. For instance

```
1.0 / n
```

You'll also need to declare `x1` to be a floating point value and use `%f`. It's no good trying to approximate `e` with an integer variable.

I guess that you will, at some point, need to implement a loop termination condition. And as it stands, your loop is rather pointless because none of the values used inside the loop ever change.

Here's a program that is perhaps moving in the right direction:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int n = 1; n <= 1000; n++)
    {
        double e = pow(1 + 1.0 / n, n);
        printf("n=%d, approximation to e=%.16f\n", n, e);
    }
    printf("true value of e=%.16f\n", exp(1.0));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
n=1, approximation to e=2.0000000000000000
n=2, approximation to e=2.2500000000000000
n=3, approximation to e=2.3703703703703698
n=4, approximation to e=2.4414062500000000
n=5, approximation to e=2.4883199999999994
n=6, approximation to e=2.5216263717421135
n=7, approximation to e=2.5464996970407121
n=8, approximation to e=2.5657845139503479
n=9, approximation to e=2.5811747917131984
n=10, approximation to e=2.5937424601000023
..........
n=991, approximation to e=2.7169116115768883
n=992, approximation to e=2.7169129915688766
n=993, approximation to e=2.7169143687840753
n=994, approximation to e=2.7169157432307069
n=995, approximation to e=2.7169171149169880
n=996, approximation to e=2.7169184838514693
n=997, approximation to e=2.7169198500421694
n=998, approximation to e=2.7169212134981109
n=999, approximation to e=2.7169225742266474
n=1000, approximation to e=2.7169239322355936
true value of e=2.7182818284590451
```

It's quite interesting to note that the rate of convergence is really poor. And the accuracy of the estimate can never be good because for large `n` you will suffer round off in `1.0 + 1.0 / n`. This is absolutely not a useful way to approximate `e`.

This version, using an [infinite sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29), converges much more rapidly:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double e = 0.0;
    double increment = 1.0;
    for (int n = 0; n <= 20; n++)
    {
        e += increment;
        increment /= (n+1);
        printf("n=%d, approximation to e=%.16f\n", n, e);
    }
    printf("true value of e=%.16f\n", exp(1.0));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
n=0, approximation to e=1.0000000000000000
n=1, approximation to e=2.0000000000000000
n=2, approximation to e=2.5000000000000000
n=3, approximation to e=2.6666666666666665
n=4, approximation to e=2.7083333333333330
n=5, approximation to e=2.7166666666666663
n=6, approximation to e=2.7180555555555554
n=7, approximation to e=2.7182539682539684
n=8, approximation to e=2.7182787698412700
n=9, approximation to e=2.7182815255731922
n=10, approximation to e=2.7182818011463845
n=11, approximation to e=2.7182818261984929
n=12, approximation to e=2.7182818282861687
n=13, approximation to e=2.7182818284467594
n=14, approximation to e=2.7182818284582302
n=15, approximation to e=2.7182818284589949
n=16, approximation to e=2.7182818284590429
n=17, approximation to e=2.7182818284590455
n=18, approximation to e=2.7182818284590455
n=19, approximation to e=2.7182818284590455
n=20, approximation to e=2.7182818284590455
true value of e=2.7182818284590451
```